# ID transformation from ABAP variable to XML does nothing

Tags: xml, transformation, abap

I experience a confusing issue with built-in SAP transformation `ID`.

I try to serialize ABAP structure, but result XML is always empty. Do you have any suggestions, what is wrong with my code?

```
DATA lv_xml TYPE xstring.

CALL TRANSFORMATION ID
  SOURCE test = syst
  RESULT XML = lv_xml.

IF lv_xml IS INITIAL.
  MESSAGE `Oops, it's empty!` TYPE 'S' DISPLAY LIKE 'W'.
ELSE.
  CALL FUNCTION 'DISPLAY_XML_STRING'
    EXPORTING
      xml_string = lv_xml.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost correct:

```
CALL TRANSFORMATION ID
  SOURCE test = syst
  RESULT XML lv_xml. " no = here!
```

The other syntax is correct as well, it just does something completely different: it searches for an element named `XML` and assigns the value of that element to `lv_xml`. Since there's no `XML` element, the string stays empty.

Comment: Oh, that amazing syntax! Just a single little sign turned into big trouble... Thank you for your answer, now the problem is solved.